# Access ServletContext resources in CDI Extension

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm facing the following situation: I have written a CDI extension, with which I want to programatically register additional beans into the `BeanManager`. I've already implemented the extension and registered in in the `META-INF/services` folder. Everything works fine so far and I can trace the container calling this method:

```
public class TestCdiExtension implements Extension {

  public void observeAfterBeanDiscovery(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery event, BeanManager manager) {
    // Code goes here
  }

}
```

My problem now is this: To determine which beans should be registered, I need access to the `ServletContext` of the current web application in which CDI is running.

I understand that you can use CDI completely without a servlet environment, so there is no hard link. However: How can I do the job of registering additional beans depending on what's in the `ServletContext`?

Is using an extension the correct way at all? Is there any other (better?) solution of doing this?